# PHP $_SESSION not persistant

Tags: php, session

My php session doesn't hold. I have searched through the PHP $_SESSION question but don't see any which can explain this issue.

Each time I reload the page with the PHP code below I get the output whether on my Cpanel web hosting or XAMPP localhost test server:

No Session
2

I am using XAMPP for my test server and CPanel for the hosting. In XAMPP I can see a session file placed into the /tmp directory and are using Chrome with cookies enabled. In my CPanel hosting I can't see anything created under the /tmp directory and I use MS Edge browser. The session file under XAMPP has the following text:

active1|b:1;count1|i:1;

php server version is 5.6

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    echo 'No Session<br>';
    session_start();
    echo session_status();
    $_SESSION["active1"] = true;
    $_SESSION["count1"] = 0;
}
else {
    echo 'Have Session<br>';
}
$_SESSION["count1"]++;
?>
```

Comment: Try to put `session_start();` before `if`

Comment: You can read more about in http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: You're checking whether a session is active (it never will be because you haven't activated it yet), then you say no session, then you start it, then you check the status again and it's `2` (active)…

Answer (score 5):

You always have to call *first* session_start();

See
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

session_start() **creates** a session or **resumes** the current one

Comment: You need to call it _first_, specifically

Comment: Unfortunately that was not shown in the example I had found from a site outside of php.net